Flat marginal distribution of Bayesian parameter
I am performing a Bayesian Parameter Estimation (BPE) to find the errors on best-fit values of two parameters in the optical model (in nuclear physics). These two parameters are "W_v" and "a_r". I am using 8 walkers to explore the 2D parameter space. I am using 10,000 burn-in steps and then the walkers walk for 30,000 steps. The prior distributions on "W_v" and "a_r" are flat (20 < W_v < 22 and 0.5 < a_r < 0.8). The log likelihood function looks like,

Here y_exp is the experimental y values, y_theo is the theoretical y values and dy is the errors on experimental y values. The log posterior is just the sum of log likelihood and log prior (ignoring the scaling for now). The walkers starting points are modeled as:
p0 = min_a + (max_a - min_a) * np.random.rand(nwalkers, ndim)

Here min_an and max_an are arrays of minimum and maximum values of the parameters (min_a = [20,0.5] and max_a = [22,0.8]), nwalkers=8 and ndim = 2. Once the run is finished, I get the posterior distributions of the parameters something like this:

The dashed line in the middle of the marginal distribution is the mean and the two lines on the sides are 1-sigma deviations. These values are close to what I get from a regular chi-squared fitting routine (W_v = 21.1 and a_r = 0.7). While the "a_r" value seems to have settled as a nice centralized distribution, the "W_v" values are all over the place. This could mean that many local minima exist in the vicinity of the chosen prior and the walkers are getting stuck in those minima. I have tried to increase the number of steps taken by the walkers and also tried to increase the number of walkers. However, it does not make a difference in the distribution of "W_v". What else could I try so that I can get a more centralized distribution for "W_v"?
Any insights into this issue will be highly appreciated.
